# How to correct and change a static method to a non-static method for Joomla module

Tags: php, joomla, static-methods

I updated a client's Joomla from J2.5.28 to J3.6.4. I have corrected most of the errors but this one stumps me even after researching here. I'm a novice PHP programmer and know enough to fix a few things here and there. I researched this throughout the internet and on StackOverflow and simply do not understand how to fix the following error in my particular case. I understand I could just turn off error reporting; However I do not want to do that because [from what I did find] this doesn't actually solve the problem. Solving the problem and correcting the code is what is actually recommended.

**Here is the error:**

*Strict Standards: Non-static method modBtContentShowcaseHelper::fetchHead() should not be called statically in ...modules/mod_bt_contentshowcase/mod_bt_contentshowcase.php on line 64*

**Line 64 reads as follows:**

```
modBtContentShowcaseHelper::fetchHead( $params );
```

I would like to know how to correct this.

*Note: Upgrading this extension is not an option because it was customized by the developer of the extension and an upgrade would wipe everything out. Contacting them usually takes several days to get a response and I need to get this corrected*

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This is a simple error to fix, with the upgrade you just have to create a class instance before calling the method. Would you like me to write an answer for you?

Comment: Yes, please write an answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initiate the class `modBtContentShowcaseHelper`

```
$x = new modBtContentShowcaseHelper();
$x->fetchhead($params);
```

Comment: So I just need to replace line 64 with what you wrote? You said "sorry for the lack of a character" so should it read like this:

$x = new modBtContentShowcaseHelper();
$x = (>) fetchhead($params);

Comment: Replace the = with a - and then it will be fine. Replace like 64 with rhat

Comment: I tried that and while it fixes that error I keep getting more errors. Looks like the component has to be rebuilt and it's way over my head at this point. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: If you want, you could email me the module and I'll take a look at it. There is probably a lot of non static methods that were changed to static.

Comment: I would be glad to. I am not even sure how I would package it up. It's a component and there's files everywhere it seems.

Comment: Oh. Well, I could try and walk you through the errors over email if you would like. My email is mcstuffins99 @ outlook . com

Comment: I'm sending you an email right now. Thank you for your willingness to help